# Resx resource, File with relative path

Tags: c#, relative-path, resx

I'm using a externally managed resx file (non-compiled) via ResXResourceReader. I have tried using the file resources with relative paths (to the resx location) as below

```
<data name="myfilename" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef">
<value>..\..\files\a.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;Windows-1252</value>
```

But it gives error, as file not available. So how to add the file path as relative? Is it should be relative to the application's bin?

Comment: make it to relative to .exe. Use `Application.StatupPath` as .exe location.

Comment: Try setting the [ResXResourceReader.BasePath Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.basepath.aspx) first, before enumerating any resources. The `BasePath` property is used to resolve relative file paths. By default, all relative file paths are resolved using [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) if the `BasePath` property value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @IronGeek, able to resolve via

ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(resourcePath);
rsxr.BasePath = "basepath"